# ¿Por qué la animación de details no funcionaa en Safari ni Chrome?

Tags: html, css, transition

Quisiera darle una animación a `details` cuando se abre e intenté con:

## `transition`

Esta fue la forma más sencilla:

```css
details p {
    transition: background-color 1s;
    background-color: red;
}

details[open] p {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>África</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, aut.</p>
</details>
```

Pero no se aplica la transición en Chrome ni en Safari como se muestra a continuación:

| Firefox | Chrome, Safari |
| --- | --- |
| [image: firefox] | [image: chrome] |

## `animation`

Usando la respuesta de [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213329/how-to-add-css3-transition-with-html5-details-summary-tag-reveal) intenté con:

```css
@keyframes transformColor {
    from {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

details[open] p {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    animation: transformColor 1s;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>África</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, aut.</p>
</details>
```

Y me funciona bien esta opción en Chrome pero en Safari solo se ejecuta una vez la animación:

[image: safari]

---

¿Hay alguna forma que la animación se vea como en Firefox?, no importa si es con `transition` o con `animation`.

---

Versiones:

- Chrome 89
- Safari (para ios 14.4.12)
- Firefox 89

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no te lo toma porque no tiene las versiones definidas en css.

acá te dejo esto:

```css
@keyframes transformColor {
    from {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
details[open] p {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  -webkit-animation: transformColor 1s; /* Safari y Chrome */
  -moz-animation: transformColor 1s;/* Firefox */
  -o-animation: transformColor 1s; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-animation: transformColor 1s; /* Opera */
  animation: transformColor 1s;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>África</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, aut.</p>
</details>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: En ios aún se ejecuta una sola vez la animación :c

Comment: disculpa que no pude ver en ese navegador ya que para windows no hay actualizaciones de ese navegador, la otra que te queda es hacerlo con `JS`